# Searching for elements and setting pagination only on these searched elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have this problem: for example, I will search for the phrase `ab` for 45 results. How to set pagination to include only 45 results, not all elements? He is currently looking for 45 items for me. But when I go to the other side, it includes all the elements for me, not just the ones I searched for.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: []
    };
  }

    searchTodo = debounce((query) => {
      this.setState({
        query
      })

      this.getTodo((query), 200)
    })

    getTodos = (number) => {

      const params = {
        expand: 'project',
        'per-page': 20,
        'page': number      
      }

      axios({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
        method: "GET"
      })
      .then(res => { 
        this.setState({
          todos: res.data
        });


      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      }) 
    }


  handlePage = (number) => {
    this.getTodos(number);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          <SearchInput onChange={e => this.searchTodo(e)} />
        </p>
          <Pagination
            itemsCountPerPage={20}
            totalItemsCount={this.state.todos.length}
            onChange={this.handlePage}
          />   
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you put this code in codesandbox

Comment: @mabhijith95a10 I can't provide a real url. I had to paste a sample. This sample does not support pagination. Also, uploading to codesandbox will not help